# Relative clause as a subject predicate

Tags: relative-clauses, predicate

Can which-clause function as a subject predicate like this?

> That is which we had to overcome and penetrate.

It sounds weird to me, but is it a correct use of grammar?

Comment: You should use *what* there, not *which*.

Comment: @Robusto https://genius.com/Godspeed-you-black-emperor-static-lyrics I thought that's what must be the case. But here, the preacher (this music is purely instrumental, with occasional long narratives and speeches) says this: That is which the prophet and the Urim and Thummim has penetrated.

Comment: Sounds like they're being pseudo-archaic, fake high-toned English which may work for dopey lyrics but not for real speech/writing.

Comment: @Robusto Oh thanks. So they are really archaic either?

Comment: It could have been used in some mangled passage in the Bible or something. But I've never encountered any such usage.

Comment: And I realize you have no control over this, but I would probably have said, "That is which the prophet and the Urim and Thummim **have** penetrated."